# High temperature expansion in general

Tags: statistical-mechanics, temperature, approximations

I'm referencing [this thesis](https://www.research-collection.ethz.ch/bitstream/handle/20.500.11850/117762/eth-49160-02.pdf?sequence=2&isAllowed=y) which should be open-access.

In Appendix D.1 "High temperature expansion in general", the author writes the high temperature expansion in the following way:

$$
\begin{align*}
\langle \hat{O} \rangle
&= \frac{\sum_i \langle i| \hat{O} e^{-\beta \hat{H}} |i\rangle}{\sum_i \langle i|  e^{-\beta \hat{H}} |i\rangle} \\
&= \beta^0 \Bigl[ \frac{1}{\Theta} \mathrm{Tr}(\hat{O})\Bigr] -\beta^1 \Bigl[ \frac{1}{\Theta} \mathrm{Tr}(\hat{O}\hat{H}) - \frac{1}{\Theta^2} \mathrm{Tr}(\hat{O})\mathrm{Tr}(\hat{H}) \Bigr] \\
&\qquad + \beta^2 \Bigl[ \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\Theta} \mathrm{Tr}(\hat{O}\hat{H}^2) - \frac{1}{\Theta^2} \mathrm{Tr}(\hat{OH})\mathrm{Tr}(\hat{H}) \\
&\qquad\quad - \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\Theta^2} \mathrm{Tr}(\hat{O})\mathrm{Tr}(\hat{H}^2) + \frac{1}{\Theta^3} \mathrm{Tr}(\hat{O})\mathrm{Tr}(\hat{H})^2 \Bigr] + \mathcal{O}(\beta^3)
\end{align*}
$$
where $\hat{O}$ is some operator and trace is over multiparticle states $|i\rangle$; $\Theta \equiv \mathrm{Tr}(I)$ is the dimension of the problem.

---

My question is: How did they do this expansion? (My attempt:)
Clearly there has been an expansion of the exponential in the numerator in terms of $\beta$,
$$
\sum_i \langle i| \hat{O} e^{-\beta \hat{H}} |i\rangle = \sum_m \frac{(-\beta)^m}{m!} \sum_i \langle i| \hat{O} \hat{H}^m |i\rangle \tag{1}
$$

but I'm not sure 1) how or where $\Theta$ comes from, and also 2) why there is a split of the traced terms: $\mathrm{Tr}(\hat{O}\hat{H})$, $\mathrm{Tr}(\hat{O})\mathrm{Tr}(\hat{H})$ in $\beta^1$ for example.
And also 3) how to formally divide out the denominator $\sum_i \langle i|  e^{-\beta \hat{H}} |i\rangle$, like after substituting (1) back into the original equation:

$$
\frac{\sum_i \langle i| \hat{O} \hat{H}^m |i\rangle}{\sum_i \langle i|  e^{-\beta \hat{H}} |i\rangle} = \text{terms for each $\beta^m$}
$$

Can someone enlighten me on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To first order in $\beta$, the numerator reads
   $$\eqalign{
   \sum_i<i|Oe^{-\beta H}|i>
   &=\sum_i <i|O|i>-\beta\sum_i<i|OH|i>\cr
   &={\rm Tr}\ \!O-\beta\ \!{\rm Tr}\ \!OH\cr
   }$$
while the denominator is
   $$\eqalign{
   \sum_i<i|e^{-\beta H}|i>
   &=\sum_i <i|i>-\beta\sum_i<i|H|i>\cr
   &=\Theta-\beta\ \!{\rm Tr}\ \!H\cr
   &=\Theta\Big(1-{\beta\over\Theta}\ \!{\rm Tr}\ \!H\Big)\cr
   }$$
Since $\beta$ is small, the inverse is (to first order)
   $${1\over\Theta}\Big(1-{\beta\over\Theta}\ \!{\rm Tr}\ \!H\Big)^{-1}={1\over\Theta}\Big(1+{\beta\over\Theta}\ \!{\rm Tr}\ \!H\Big)$$
The average is finally to first order in $\beta$
   $$\eqalign{
   \langle O\rangle&={1\over\Theta}\Big({\rm Tr}\ \!O-\beta\ \!{\rm Tr}\ \!OH\Big)\Big(1+{\beta\over\Theta}\ \!{\rm Tr}\ \!H\Big)\cr
&={1\over\Theta}{\rm Tr}\ \!O
-{\beta\over\Theta}{\rm Tr}\ \!OH
+{\beta\over\Theta^2}{\rm Tr}\ \!O\ {\rm Tr}\ \!H\cr
   }$$
I let you extend the calculation to higher orders.

Comment: There's a typo for your denominator line, but otherwise I get the gist of the method. Thank you! ($\sum_i<i|e^{-\beta H}|i>$, not $\sum_i<i|Oe^{-\beta H}|i>$.)

Comment: Thanks! I have updated the answer. I am happy to have been helpful!